# Personal computer failed to access maven central

Tags: java, maven

I have a PC that installed with gaming app like `Steam` or `GOG` but in Windows config there is no proxy and no firewall other than default ones from the OS. I have `NordVPN` but currently disconnected. However after installed maven 3.8.2, all `mvn` goal failed that can't access maven central

```
PS C:\Dev\Code\intellij\my-test> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId="com.my.app" -DartifactId="mydemo" -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype-quickstart" -DinteractiveMode="false"
```

threw following error

```
[WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.404 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-24T17:29:01-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\me\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Anyone has experience to troubleshooting such issue? There is no addtional configuration from `settings.xml`, everything is original from maven zip file directory downloaded from maven site

PS: it is the same behavior with command line or Intellij or Eclipse. It's not an issue with IDE but rather something in the environment/OS blocking maven, just hopefully can have some way to debug the issue

Comment: Do you get an answer if you open the urls from the error message in a browser?

Comment: *This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted...*. Try manually deleting broken artifacts under your `.m2` folder

Comment: Try adding a '-X' and '> output.txt'.  The X will raise the output to debug level.  The other portion will route the output to a file.

Comment: So, It's unlikely that steam or gog are affecting the connection, however NordVPN, so question is, what's the status of you Internet connection? Or is its specific to Maven? And also how did the vpn disconnect - VPN software usually edit your hosts file and updates your dns server settings, did you check both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the cause of this issue is I am running `OpenJDK8` in local environment where the certificate Maven is expired, upgraded to latest `OpenJDK` resolved the issue. @ProgrammersBlock's advice of using -X definitely is also very helpful to identify the problem